# Google Slides Apps Script Change Theme

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Is there a way to automatically change the theme of multiple Google Slides using Apps Script?

At least, is there a way to select multiple and change the theme together?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "theme" in this situation? Could you share a screenshot of what is your expected result?

Comment: Once a slide is opened, on the tool bar towards the far right there is Background, Layout, Theme, Transition.  That theme.  When you click Theme you see options like this in the sidebar - Simple Light, Simple Dark, Streamline, Focus, Shift, Momentum, etc.

Comment: I think you will need to use a workaround because you cannot select the predefined themes from Apps Script. You could just implement your own created apps Script. Would that work for you? Do you have any examples of how do you want to look at the end? Could you share your code or a sample slide to see if we can work from there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73646794/3525368