# How to change a Google Slides presentation theme via Slides API?

Tags: google-slides-api

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870270/google-slides-api-how-way-change-theme-via-api) question. However, nobody has answered it.
So, how can you change a presentation's theme via the API? Is it even possible? I'm using Java, but that shouldn't affect the API.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You can do two things:

1. Import a scheme from a [master](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create) when creating your presentation - as suggested in the post you are refering to
2. Change the exsiting theme with a [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) [UpdatePagePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatepagepropertiesrequest) or [UpdateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest) request:

   - Thereby you can specify theme colors within the update request.
   - Sample from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/elements?hl=en#copy_and_edit_an_element):

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateShapeProperties": {
        "objectId": copyElementId,
        "fields": "shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color",
        "shapeProperties": {
          "shapeBackgroundFill": {
            "solidFill": {
              "color": {
                "themeColor": "LIGHT2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**References:**

- [Pages, Page Elements, and Properties](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/page-elements?hl=en)
- [Kind of properties](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/page-elements?hl=en#kinds_of_properties)
- [ThemeColorType](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#themecolortype)
- [ColorScheme](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#colorscheme)
- [PageProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#pageproperties)
- [PredefinedLayout](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request?hl=en#predefinedlayout)